# 200 Rep Limit over what period exactly?

Tags: discussion, reputation

SO has a limit on the amount of reputation that can be earnt **per day** of 200 (there are exceptions but this question isn't about that).

My question is exactly what constitutes **a day**?  Is it any 24 hour period?

Or is it the date as viewed from a specific time zone?  If so does this put some at  disadvantage due to the time zone they live in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's 24 hours in UTC.

See the explanation in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow/7238#7238).

Comment: The FAQ link you post states "(A new day starts 0:00 UTC == 7pm EST == 4pm PST == 1am CET)."   IOW it is viewed from a specific time zone.

Comment: The SO timezone is UTC. Time period for the rep cap is 0:00 UTC to 24:00 UTC. The other time zones are only there to give an overview what that means to your timezone if you are not a UTCer.

Answer (score 2):

24 hours.  I see no disadvantage depending on your time zone. We all get 24 hours each, right?

Comment: The point is the 24 hours starts at the same time (00:00 UTC) for everyone globally.  It isn't a rolling 24 hour period.

Comment: However you are correct there isn't actually any advantage.

Answer (score 1):

For me personally, the rep limits go from 8pm EST to 8pm EST, due to Daylight Savings Time. Once the clocks roll back again, it will return to 7pm EST to 7pm EST.

I wouldn't necessarily say that there are any advantages involved in what the time period is. The only disadvantage is if your day happens to revolve around time periods when the vast majority of users are not using the site. For those of us in America and in the UK, are activity coincides nicely with the activity of other users, which makes it easy to hit rep cap.

Comment: You lousy Northern Hemisphereans.

Comment: Small clarification. In the summer, we are in Daylight Saving Time which is denoted with the abbreviation (E **D** T). So the rep limits go from 8pm E **D** T to 8pm E **D** T. When the clocks go back, Eastern Standard Time is abbreviated (E **S** T).