# When does the rep cap reset for the day?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [200 Rep Limit over what period exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18404/200-rep-limit-over-what-period-exactly)

At what time of the day does the 200 rep cap limit reset.  For example as of 4:24pm today I have earned 97 reps for the day.  So "today" I earned 97 reps.  What time of the day does "tomorrow" begin whereby I will have earned 0 reps thus resetting the 200 rep daily limit.

Comment: Certainly a dup, but 00:00Z - i.e. UTC midnight. It is currently 21:32:43 in UTC time, so add 2½ hours to your local time.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18404/200-rep-limit-over-what-period-exactly

Comment: Thanks John - I had to disappear, so couldn't look it up.

Answer (score 2):

4:00 PM Pacific Standard Time
5:00 PM Mountain Standard Time
6:00 PM Central Standard Time
7:00 PM Eastern Standard Time

And I do not believe it shifts for daylight time savings ... but I cannot confirm that.

For all other times, see [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=1&day=14&year=2010&hour=16&min=0&sec=0&p1=0).

Comment: Which CST do you mean? I know of three different time zones, all called CST :)

Comment: Fixed :) Now I'm waiting for the next flaw in my post to be spotted!

Comment: Why America, of course!  Nothing else *really* exits, you know.  You are merely a fig newton of our collective imagination.

Comment: @Chacha102: Central Standard Time US, right? Because one of the other CSTs is Central Standard Time in Australia :)

Comment: @Jon Just go answer a C# question or something....

Comment: `EST` also applies to every country that has an Eastern border...

Answer (score 1):

About when I go to bed.

I've been meaning to ask Jeff to make that more accurate...

(But yes, midnight UTC in reality.)

Comment: You need a little red button on the side of your bed. When you press it, the rep cap resets :)

Comment: @Chacha: given that I usually sleep with my phone near by (at least when I'm on call) I should write an android app that detects sleep-style breathing. It could also alert me if a C# question is posted just before I drift off...